# yum install overwrite manual installation

Tags: centos, yum

*Note: I barely know what I'm doing here, as such this may be incredibly obvious, but I wasn't able to find what I was after on Google.*

*Running CentOS 6.7*

Yesterday I followed [this guide to set up opendkim](https://www.howtoforge.com/set-up-dkim-domainkeys-identified-mail-working-with-postfix-on-centos-using-opendkim) on my server, and as far as I can tell it is working.

This guide told me to get the opendkim package via

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/opendkim/files/opendkim-2.4.2.tar.gz
```

along with

```
tar zxvf opendkim-2.4.2.tar.gz
cd opendkim-2.4.2
./configure --sysconfdir=/etc --prefix=/usr/local --localstatedir=/var
make
make install
```

I've since found out this is not the latest version (I know I should have checked that first -__-). I found an updated version of the guide showing this can now be installed via `yum install opendkim`.

I would like to move to using that method, but I don't know enough about this stuff to know if that will overwrite things cleanly - or even at all.

**What's the safest/best way to install opendkim with yum while removing/overwriting the manual installation** (while keeping my configuration ideally - but that can be redone if necessary)

Comment: Presumably you just have to clean up the stuff that was installed under /usr/local/ and then install the package.

Comment: Ok, so there's a bunch of stuff in **/usr/local..** `/bin, /include, /lib, /sbin, /share/doc, /share/man/man5, /share/man/man8` If I just delete all that, then `yum install ..` it that should do the job?

Comment: No, because other things may also have been installed there! Check the date on the files there and remove those that have a date from the day you installed opendkim.

Comment: So I just ran `find . -type f -newermt 20151221 \! -newermt 20151223
` to find all the modified files in the `/usr/local` directory. Do I need to search any other folders? If I delete all these files will that be enough?

Comment: Often packages set up for `./configure` have an `uninstall` target, try `make uninstall`

Comment: What vonbrand said (you may want to save your config first), but otherwise the stuff that got installed elsewhere won't get in the way after you've installed the packaged version.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to check if your compilled program have an uninstall target.
So you can begin with a fresh environement.

If you would like that yum override file, you should know how yum work.

Lets take the exemple of nginx package. You have a `%file` selection that describe all the files the packages will install.

a part of this section look like

```
%files
%license LICENSE
%doc CHANGES README
%{nginx_datadir}/html/*
%{_sbindir}/nginx
%{_datadir}/vim/vimfiles/ftdetect/nginx.vim
%{_mandir}/man8/nginx-upgrade.8*
%{_unitdir}/nginx.service
%config(noreplace) %{nginx_confdir}/fastcgi.conf
%config(noreplace) %{nginx_confdir}/fastcgi.conf.default
```

here you can check, you have 2 kind of files
files that prefixed with `%config` and file that not

the biavior is different for the two kind of files.
Basic file is silently ignored and replaced by rpm version

Config file depend of the `noreplace` biavior, if the `noreplace` flag is set, your config file will not be overwritten and the rpm version will be add to the same dirrectory with an `.rpmnew` extension

If this flag is not present, your current file will be saved in the same dir with `.rpmsave` extension and the package configuration will be deployed.

If you would like to return to rpm version, you had just to remove the files the package insert in /etc or use the rpm notice to remove and move the correct files.

Answer (score 0):

One not so sample method is to check with `make` what exactly files are copied and remove/save them and then install with `yum` and make changes (if already configured old install).

The command is

```
make -n install
```

This will not execute the install but only display the commands which `make install` will do. So you can grab the output, edit it and replace copy command with remove. And exec it to remove the installation from source.

And then install with `yum`